# JMeter - Execution Order?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a test plan configured as so:

[image: Jmeter]

When I execute the test plan, all 3 simple controllers are executed at the same time, even though I have 1 thread set and 1 loop.

I want it to execute samples in "XML Import" then "UI - Quick Entry" then "UI - Reprint" rather than them all being executed at the same time.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure they are running in parallel? JMeter executes the components in sequential order from top to bottom. Add View Results Tree and check.

Comment: Yeah, As two of them are Webdriver Samplers (Reprint and Quick Entry) and they are both opening and running firefox at the same time, and its breaking the tests...

Comment: please add JMeter version?

Comment: the version is 3.0 r1743807

Comment: I tried to simulate the same example. What I observed is that it reused the already launched WebDriver instance (i.e., Firefox browser). My first webdriver sampler (second Simple Controller) visits one website, and the second webdriver sampler (third Simple Controller) visits another website. Are you referring this behaviour as parallel? Or completely different behavior, like launching two Firefox browsers parallelly? I also tried on 3.0 version.

Comment: Are your WebDriver samples waiting for something? Maybe not so they start almost at the same time? Refer: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: from jmeter.log file `com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig: Thread: Thread Group 1-1 already has a WebDriver(ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (10e4ef31a9d046f8e4fa38f9592437e9)) associated with it. ThreadGroup can only contain a single WebDriverConfig`

Comment: your script is somehow misconfigured, but question has too few details to figure out what. Therefore I don't think question or answer would be useful for anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

You can have only one [Firefox Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FirefoxDriverConfig/) element per [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), each thread (virtual user) will kick off a separate browser instance.

JMeter executes samplers upside down (unless you have [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) specifying different behaviour). See [Using Selenium with JMeter's WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) for more details on Selenium and JMeter integration.

Answer (score -1):

I had to move the two webdrivers into their own threads, this is now working as I expected it to.